# How to find max value from column of oracle table?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am trying to find max value from a column id for a table student in oracle database.The query given below is working fine till the id<=9.
for eg
table data

```
id
--
3
6
9

sql> select id from (select * from Student order by id desc)Student where rownum<=1 order by id desc;

id
--
9
```

but though id=10 is present in records it's still giving me id=9 as max value.
for eg
table data

```
id
--
3
6
9
10

sql> select id from (select * from Student order by id desc)Student where rownum<=1 order by id desc;

id
--
9
```

please help.

Comment: use max function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you can't get the max value is simple. Your `id` column probably is not `number` type but rather `char` type. When you do `order by` oracle treats `char` type differently, it takes the first character of `'10'` which is `'1'` compare with the first character of `'9'` which is `'9'` so `'9'` is still the maximum value.

To fix fix this , you should make sure your `id` is number:

```
select id 
from (select * from Student order by TO_NUMBER(id) desc)Student 
where rownum<=1 order by TO_NUMBER(id) desc;
```

But you can use this query as well:

```
select max(TO_NUMBER(id)) from student;
```